# changing git directory to previous one

Tags: git

I have a project directory like /projects/myProject/src/...
and my git repository is on /projects/myProject/src directory. But I want to change my main git directory to /projects/myProject(which is the parent of current git directory.)
I could just create a new repo on /projects/myProject, but I could lose all of my previous commits. Is there a way to change my directory without loosing my commit data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Within the `/src` folder, Perform a move of `*` to `./src` so now your code should all be in `/src/src`. If you do the move correctly it'll keep all the revision history.
2. Move all content from `/myproject/` to `/myproject/src` and then commit it.
3. Rename `/myproject/src` to `/myproject/myproject` and then move the entire directory tree down one.

That should retain your commit history.

**Example**

*Before:*

- `/Myproj.make`
- `/src/.git`
- `/src/myproj.cpp`

*Next Step:*

- `/Myproj.make`
- `/src/.git`
- `/src/src/myproj.cpp`

*Next Step:*

- `/src/.git`
- `/src/Myproj.make`
- `/src/src/myproj.cpp`
- **[COMMIT]**

*Next Step:*

- `/.git`
- `/Myproj.make`
- `/src/myproj.cpp`
- **[DONE]**